# How can I view the Eclipse platform logging?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, accurev

I am using the AccuBridge plugin for AccuRev. This plugin uses the acdiffgui tool for carrying out diffs. The acdiffgui tool lives in /usr/bin as a symbolic link:

`acdiffgui -> /opt/accurev/bin/acdiffgui`

This works fine within Eclipse; I can diff two files with no problem. However, the acdiffgui tool is rather limited and I would like to use Meld instead.

Because there is no way to configure this from within the plugin itself I updated the symbolic link to point to the meld tool:

`acdiffgui -> /usr/bin/meld`

Now when I try to diff two files nothing happens, not even an error! Therefore, I'd be interested in looking at the Eclipse output to see if there is any indication as to what is going wrong.

I've looked at the /.metadata/.log file but no errors appearing. Is this the correct place to look, and if so, is there a way to increase the logging level?

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I managed to get the acdiffgui problem sorted - but I'd still be interested in the Eclipse logging aspect of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the menu: `Window -> Show View -> Error Log`

Or from the file system look for `<workspace-directory>/.metadata/.log`   is the path used when you start eclipse